# Laravel 6.2- Using @php ...-. @endphp does not work but <?php ---- ?> does?

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to use @php....@endphp to code some data in a Laravel blade file as follows

```
<div class="row">
                  @php
                         $count =count($doc_list);
                            if(!empty($chk_doc_list)){
                                $arrColumns = array_column($chk_doc_list,'docType');
                           }
                        @endphp
                         @for($i=0;$i<$count;$i+=2)
                         @php
                           $c1=$i;$c2=$c1+1;
                           $n1=$c1+1;
                           $n2=$c2+1;
                         @endphp
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="row listview">
                          <div class="col-md-11">
                            {{$n1}}. {{$doc_list[$c1]->TDM_Doc_Name}}
                         </div>
                          <div class="col-md-1 listicon">
                             @if(!empty($arrColumns))
                                @if(in_array($doc_list[$c1]->TDM_Doc,$arrColumns))
                                  <i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i> 
                                @endif
                             @endif
                          

                            <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" class="minimal"></label> -->
                          
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                    @if($c2<$count)
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row listview">
                            <div class="col-md-11">
                            
                                {{$n2}}. {{$doc_list[$c2]->TDM_Doc_Name}}
                              
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 listicon">
                              @if(!empty($arrColumns))
                                @if(in_array($doc_list[$c2]->TDM_Doc,$arrColumns)) 
                                <i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i> 
                                @endif 
                              @endif

                              <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" class="minimal"></label> -->
                           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  @endif
                @endfor
                  </div>
```

However, the code didnt work. The browser (I tried with 4 of them) was unable to identify `$count` in   `@for($i=0;$i<$count;$i+=2)` line.

But, when I changed `@php` to `<?php` and `@endphp` to `?>` ,it worked.
So, what was the problem with the first one?

Comment: pure php code has to be inside <?php

Comment: Do you use `.blade.php` as your filename extension?

Comment: @hmrneves that is not the case in blade

Comment: This is not proper, do your logic in the controller and pass the results to the view. Also, "the code didn't work" is not a good problem statement.